# GameObject上にカウントダウンテキスト表示するには

Tags: unity3d

初めまして。

私はUnityで、
移動するゲームオブジェクト上に
カウントダウンテキストを表示させたいと思っているのですがどのように実現すれば良いでしょうか？

Unityのバージョンは4.6なので、新規のUIを使用するのかとも思ったのですが上手くいかず。。
アドバイスいただければと思います。

※ジャンルは2Dゲームになります。

Comment: gameobjectのタグを追加しました。

Comment: 下記の回答ありがとうございました！
お返事遅れて申し訳ございません。

結局、ゲームの見た目に汎用性を持たせたくて、
カウントダウン表示をSpriteの絵として、
カウントダウン処理中にSpriteを差し替える事で対応しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity4.6でも旧3DTextは使えますが、Createの選択には現れなくなっています。
カウントダウンテキストはCanvasの下に配置して表示するのには考慮が必要そうですし、今の時点では旧3DTextを使うのが早いと思います。

使うには空のGameObjectを作るなどして、`Add Component`から`TextMesh`コンポーネントを追加してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: @Font こちらの回答で問題は解決したでしょうか。ご確認のうえで解決済にマークしていただけると双方の信頼度がプラスされます。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

uGUI(Unity4.6からのGUI)でキャンバスを作成し、CanvasのRenderModeを”World Space”に変更、Canvasの中に作ったTextが、オブジェクトを追随するようにするのが一番スマートじゃないでしょうか?